# Comedy skits for learning French

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

I am looking for small comedy skits in French language. I need this to learn French and also act the skit for my teacher. It would be great if I have some links to some website containing these skits.

Comment: Les mots d'Éric et Ramzy si tu veux désapprendre c'est pas mal. De l'autre côté du spectre tu as le Professeur Rollin.

Comment: @pradeept : a famous French tv seri https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dRqt005w2Gg#t=107 As it’s on youtube, automatic translation is available through subtitling.

Answer (score 7):

Comedy in French quite often rely on play of words, regional / foreign accents and idiosyncracies, or pre-conceived ideas tightly linked to the French culture. This is definitely not the easiest way to learn the language.

However, if you are a motivated beginner, you can look for sketches by [Raymond Devos](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Devos), [Pierre Desproges](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Desproges) or [Daniel Prévost](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Pr%C3%A9vost_%28com%C3%A9dien%29), which in my opinion are easiest to understand.

For an intermediate level, you could be interested in sketches by [Jamel Debbouze](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamel_Debbouze), [Gad Elmaleh](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gad_Elmaleh), [Florence Foresti](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Foresti) or [Anthony Cavanagh](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Kavanagh). But keep in mind these comedians have or fake accents, and often use slang.

And for very advanced levels, you can try the best of them all : [Coluche](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coluche).

Comment: Let's maybe add to these already good references just this one : [Pierre Dac](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Dac) (perfect and clear language, but maybe slightly harder to find).

Comment: On another note, I'd find Jamel Debbouze *much* harder to understand for a foreign learner than Coluche. (I like them both very much, that's really not the point please let's not fall in that trolling trap)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Really? Well, I might be biaised because I was a kid when I heard Coluche for the first time (and almost didn't get a word of it), while I kind of grew up with Jamel later in my teen years, and the slang he uses is the exact same slang I use(d) everyday. And thanks for reminding me of Pierre Dac!

Comment: I'm 37 and still have issues understanding Djamel. I also (and probably it's related) hardly laugh at him, but that's another story. From my point of view, Raymond Devos is also very hard to understand, a lot of very complicated play of words. That said, it seems you just forgot (or omitted) about almost 2 decades of comedians in your list. I would suggest Pierre Palmade, Muriel Robin, Bigard, Anne Roumanoff, patrick Timsit, Elie Semoun, Elie Kakou; And for the more recent ones, Jeremie Ferrari, Olivier Debenoist, Arnaud Tsamère. This list is of course also very incomplete...

Comment: Not an omission, just an overlook from my side. That's definitely a list of comedians worth looking into for an intermediate level, and I'd also add Les Nuls and Les Inconnus, for which material can be very easily found online, perhaps even more than the others.

Answer (score 3):

Like Alexis said, it might be hard to learn French with Comedy Skit since most of humorists rely on slang and "inside-jokes" of the culture they are talking to.

I would like to add some to his list, mostly people from Quebec, since that's where I'm from.

If you want really short sketches, I think [François Pérusse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_P%C3%A9russe) is a good choice. You can find most of his work on Grooveshark [right here](http://grooveshark.com/#!/francoisperusse). He made a lot of « 2 minutes du peuple » both in Quebec and France (so sometimes you can even compare the same sketch in Quebec French and France French).

Else, you could go for sketches written by some very well known stand-up comics like [Yvon Deschamps](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yvon_Deschamps), [Louis-José Houde](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Jos%C3%A9_Houde) or [Martin Matte](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Matte).

If you really want a challenge, and you are up to analyze the texts after listening them, I would consider listening to [Marc Favreau](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Favreau) and his famous character [Sol](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_%28personnage%29). His sketches are very well known  but could be hard to understand as they play a lot with the meaning of words. His text [L'Adversité](http://stop-tabac.ch/blog/nichat/weblog.pl) is very well written (Sorry I couldn't find a better source).

You might also want [to watch this small sketch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWpegQBo0Hc&list=PL28896832AA3DF348) with Marc Favreau which is an educational and funny episode from a TV show meant to *teach [English] students basic French linguistics*. The first 8 minutes get you through the whole sketch with translations and then the last 6 minute are the same sketch without any stop (so you can see if you remember).